# Embedded Java database allowing concurrent reads from different JVM instances?

Tags: java, database

Is there an embedded Java RDBMS that supports multiple concurrent readers from different JVM instances?

Comment: I don't believe there is such a database which allows updating as well. One way around this is to have a "master" database which is replicated.  Each reader works off a copy of the master database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Derby has a **network** mode, as do most of the embedded Java database solutions, but then it ceases to be purely **embedded**. You can also use JNDI in a J2EE container to share references to embedded databases like Derby amongst separate Web Apps.

Comment: Yes, appears to be a choice between embedded+single-reader and client/server+multi-reader. I need to deploy as a stand alone executable jar, so I went with embedded and disallowed simultaneous reading.

Comment: @Matthew you can do embedded with multiple web apps with Derby, if you create the Derby instance at the container level, and make the `DataSource` object available to all the web apps from the `global` context. I have done this successfully with Tomcat and Jetty. It isn't ideal to have a global context like that, but it is reasonable in this specific instance.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [HyperSQL](http://hsqldb.org/web/hsqlFeatures.html) for instance, it may be deployed as a standard SQL server

Comment: But then it's not really embedded. I was hoping to deploy my app as a stand-alone executable jar.